# how to generate switch case with a scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I would like generate this cases with a 
 $scope.type[i] (json array from database) , how to do that?

```js
 $scope.type = [{nomcarac: "phone"}, {nomcarac: "shoes"}];

  $scope.getValuesList = function(item) {
    switch (item.type){
      case 'phone': 
        item.valuelist = angular.copy($scope.phonelist);
        break;
      case 'shoes': 
        item.valuelist = angular.copy($scope.shoeslist);
        break;
      default:
        item.valuelist = [];
        break;
    }
  };
```

Comment: It should be switch (item.nomcarac){ or whatever that evaluates to nomrac from item

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the correct object value to switch that will match your cases. In below example if you pass phone or shoes from input the switch will trigger.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.type = [{nomcarac: "phone"}, {nomcarac: "shoes"}];

  $scope.getValuesList = function(index) {
    switch ($scope.type[index].nomcarac){
    
      case $scope.type[index].nomcarac: 
        $scope.valuelist = $scope.type[index].nomcarac +" " + "worked";
        console.log($scope.valuelist);
        break;
      default:
        $scope.valuelist = "Nothing worked";
        break;
    }
  };
  for(var i=0;i<$scope.type.length;i++)
    $scope.getValuesList(i);
   }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
</div>
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand, I would like generate case name
like: 
for var[i] i++
case '$scope.type[i].nomcarac'
I don't know how to do this

Comment: @jean Are you looking for something similar to above?

Answer (score 0):

`$scope` variables are just like normal javascript variables, you can access sub-levels by using a variable like this:

```
item.valuelist = angular.copy($scope[item.type + 'list']);
```

You can check for null later if you worry about incorrect string.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work as per your expectation **:**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.type = [{nomcarac: "phone"}, {nomcarac: "shoes"}];

    $scope.getValuesList = function(item) {
      switch (item.nomcarac) {
        case item.nomcarac:
          item.valuelist = angular.copy($scope.phonelist);
          break;
        default:
          item.valuelist = [];
          break;
      }
    };
    
    for (var i in $scope.type) {
     $scope.getValuesList($scope.type[i]);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
</div>
```